# What method of checking than setting a value is most optimal?

Tags: c#, c++, variables

This is my first post on stack overflow after being a programmer for 7 years... and I have a pretty stupid question. What is more efficient between these two? Does the C++ or C# compiler automatically optimize it and if so what does it change to?

```cpp
if(a) b=a

if(a) b=true
```

Comment: Why did you tag C#?

Comment: Because I use both languages and I was kind of interested in the answer for both... but... I guess that's a little weird. It's probably the same answer anyway.

Comment: They are 2 different statements. Can we compare apple and orange?

Comment: Oh, I should specify, "a" is literally a bool meaning that if (a) passes... "a" is true... so setting "b" equal to "a" is the same as setting "b" equal to "true".

Comment: *What is more efficient between these two?* -- That shows you've been away a long time from C++.  An optimizing C++ compiler will more than likely produce the same code, maybe remove it altogether if it sees the chance to do so.  If you want to see the underlying assembly, then go to [godbolt.org](http://godbolt.org) and enter the program.

Comment: Haha. Truth is, C++ is my second language although it is my favorite, I just don't have as much opportunity to use it. 

I tried that compiler and it does give me different results for both the situations. The first case seems to require a read and a write while the second requires just a write. Ether this compiler is not optimizing it or no compiler does. What do you think? am I using the wrong compiler?

Comment: It seems like this would have to be very specifically considered because it would only be an optimization possible for bool value types.

Comment: The second seams clearer for humans to read, and less likely to break if in the future the condition is changed to `a || c`. Another alternative is `b = b || a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# in Release Mode, they both compile to the same IL

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void M (
            bool a
        ) cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 3 (0x3)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.1
        IL_0001: pop
        IL_0002: ret
    } // end of method C::M

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2054
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

} // end of class C
```

In Debug Configuration, you have a minor difference between `b==a` one (removing the noise); see IL_0006 line.

```
// Methods
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void M (
        bool a
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 9 (0x9)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] bool,
        [1] bool
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.1
    IL_0002: stloc.1
    // sequence point: hidden
    IL_0003: ldloc.1
    IL_0004: brfalse.s IL_0008

    IL_0006: ldarg.1
    IL_0007: stloc.0

    IL_0008: ret
} // end of method C::M
```

and the b==true version

```
// Methods
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void M (
        bool a
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 9 (0x9)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] bool,
        [1] bool
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.1
    IL_0002: stloc.1
    // sequence point: hidden
    IL_0003: ldloc.1
    IL_0004: brfalse.s IL_0008

    IL_0006: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0007: stloc.0

    IL_0008: ret
} // end of method C::M
```

In practice, I would want to have benchmarked your exact usagebefore worrying about this sort of micro-optimisation. It is unlikely to be the best value for your time spent in optimisation efforts.